# Combining Azure Functions and Spring @Scheduled annotation

Tags: java, spring, azure, azure-functions, spring-scheduled

I'm using azure functions along with spring boot, in my code I have one method with `@Scheduled` annotation (with fixedDelay = 10 sec) and I'm afraid it doesn't always works well, in some cases it does, in other cases I'm getting exceptions like `ConcurrentModificationException`.

In my function I have queue trigger and in my understanding code under `@Scheduled` annotation can be only triggered when function is in "EXECUTION" state, what's more it needs additional thread and there might be some limitation from azure side like one thread per one execution etc.

The conclusion is that, serverless functions like azure ones shouldn't create any additional threads during execution, I mean only one thread is dedicated for single function execution.

Please let me know if my way of thinking is correct and if I should use some alternative solution (without creating additional threads) for handling my business logic?

Answer (score 0):

Better to user @TimerTrigger annotation for your use case instead @Scheduled which is Native for Spring Boot.

example:

@FunctionName("keepAlive")
public void keepAlive(
@TimerTrigger(name = "keepAliveTrigger", schedule = "0 */5 * * * *") String timerInfo,
ExecutionContext context
) {
// timeInfo is a JSON string, you can deserialize it to an object using your favorite JSON library
context.getLogger().info("Timer is triggered: " + timerInfo);
}

Comment: Yes, but in my case method under `@Scheduled` annotation is doing job on data produced during function execution which is triggered by queue.